# How to fill asp listview in fast time if i have thousand of rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Global.ConnectionString());
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader drReader = null;

cmd = new SqlCommand();
conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "spIndustryDataSelect";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iiProcessType", 1); 
drReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
conn.Close();

da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(dt);

lstIndustry.DataSource = dt;
lstIndustry.DataBind();
```

I using this c# code to fill the lstIndustry asp ListView, but it take a minute time because it has a thousand of rows and i need to select all, is there any method to fill the list in fast time?

Comment: No issue in your code...since it has thousands of rows then filling and displaying will take time. But why you are fetching data 2 times from database. Use datareader only. No need to use adapter and table.

Comment: Short answer: don't. Nobody scrolls thousands of entries. Use pagination.

Comment: I would recommend this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560705/infinite-scroll-asp-net-core-mvc

Comment: Can I use postback to fill the data when scrolling the page?

Comment: add a data pager to the listview- never been to a site that forces me to view and scroll thought a 1000 of anything! So, your users will hate you for doing that. However, it shouldd not be taking that long to load. 2000 rows is huge for a web browser to display - but it should only take a few seconds anyway. But then again, that few seconds delay probably is already too long. Drop in a data pager - and you only be displaying one page at a time. however, something else is going on here - since there should only be a few seconds delay - even for that many rows which is already too many

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create pagination with Using Take And Skip for improve performance
2. You can add Index on Table if You have where in sp